# Keeping "None Dataframes" when using DataFrame's Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes, and some are None (they don't have any value).
But when I DO:

```
dict_of_dfs = dict(enumerate([LIST OF DATAFRAMES]))
dframes = pd.concat(dict_of_dfs)
```

However, when I perform (this is to get normalised tables):

```
test = dframes.groupby(level=1).pipe(lambda g: dframes.sub(g.mean(), level=1).div(g.std(), level=1))
```

It looks like it's getting rid of these None dataframes.

Because I then use:

```
tmpList=[]
for date, new_df in test.groupby(level=0):
    tmpList.append(new_df)
```

This final "tmpList" will be a shorter list than my first one.

How can I do?
I basically want to transform a list of dataframes (which includes None dataframe) into a same list of dataframes (which are all normalised now).

Comment: What are you trying to capture with *None* items since they have zero rows?

Comment: It's that "dict_of_dfs" will be of different length than "tmpList" because "dict_of_dfs" contains a few None dataframes. So is there a way for "tmpList" to keep the None dataframes?

Comment: Why not keep using *dict_of_dfs*? And why do you need *None* objects which are removed in `pd.concat` and `groupby`. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please provide fuller background of whole process.

Comment: I've edited my question. I basically want to transform a list of dataframes (which includes None dataframe) into a same list of dataframes (which are all normalised now).